# How to automatically send print job from "Cloud" server to printer?

Tags: asp.net, printing, networking, cloud

A picture is supposed to be worth a 1000 words, so let's see if that can shorten this post up a bit...  Essentially, I'm looking into "how" to code a solution that runs on the web server within the cloud that will send a print command to a printer within office 1 (label printer).

The print job is really part of work flow within the ASP.NET web application and I would like to keep all of the code within a single application if possible.  How can I go about doing this?

Due to security, I should avoid creating a new application within Office 1 that pulls data from the "cloud" and have the "cloud" be used to push the command downward.  I'm really looking at this from a code standpoint within the ASP.NET app and also potentially transcending into more of a serverfault/superuser question on the printer.  I'll save that for a future question there though.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a coding perspective, starting with version 3.0 of the framework, there is the [`System.Printing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574466.aspx) namespace, which provides classes for sending print jobs to a local, remote, or dedicated printer appliance. In particular, classes of interest may be [`PrinServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printserver.aspx), [`PrintQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx), and [`PrintTicket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.aspx).

For versions of the framework prior to 3.0, you can use the [spooler api functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162861(v=VS.85).aspx) to accomplish similiar tasks. You can find some pinvoke signatures at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using Google Cloud Print.

While the repo is for Mono, it should work for C#.

[GitHub MonoGCP.](https://github.com/slackshot/MonoGCP)