# How can I print to a remote printer?

Tags: asp.net

I need to print to a remote printer that is configured in public IP. How can I achieve this?

Our application is hosted in AppHarbor and printer in another location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically send print job from "Cloud" server to printer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534925/how-to-automatically-send-print-job-from-cloud-server-to-printer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **WMI**.
Use this [msdn WMI Tasks: Printers and Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

> Add a new printer connection to a remote computer?

```
strComputer = "atl-ws-01"
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objPrinter = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Printer")
errReturn = objPrinter.AddPrinterConnection _
    ("\\PrintServer1\ArtDepartmentPrinter")
```

Check the following links for more reference:
[Remote Printing](http://forums.asp.net/t/1793299.aspx/1?Remote%20Printing)
[Print to a remote printer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1282767.aspx/1)
[print on remote printer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1677987.aspx/1)

Source: from Reference links

Not sure if I understood correctly. Do they have their field computers connected to a network printer?

If yes, just simply use JavaScript on the Print Button.

This is what I did on my print button:

```
<!--Java Script Function -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function printClicked() {
        document.getElementById('printButton').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('button1').style.display='none';
        if (document.getElementById('viewButton'))
            document.getElementById('viewButton').style.display='none';
        
        window.print();
        return false;
    }
// -->
</script>
```

Add that function to the button you got.

```
<input type="button" id="printButton" style="width:120px" runat="server" onclick="printClicked()" value="PRINT">
```

Hope these reference help.